# Arcpy Map addTable() - ValueError - SystemError: when trying add a table to map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, addtable

I have an ArcGIS Pro project and am trying to add a table created through several processes to my map at the end of the script. I've checked under options to add output from geoprocesses to open map but nothing happens.

I then tried using the Map method both by adding a view of the table to the map and adding it directly and both ways give me a value error and a system error.

Here's my code:

```
# make a table view so table is added to layout

arcpy.management.MakeTableView(user_ref_table, "records_list")

# make ArcGISProject object of map that enduser is interfacing with
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

# make map object to add table view to
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
m.addTable("records_list")
```

This is the error message:

```
ValueError: records_list

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 96, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1881, in addTable
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addTable(*gp_fixargs((add_table,), True)))
SystemError: <built-in method addTable of MappingMapObject object at 0x000001A19F177240> returned a result with an error set
Failed script Get Daily Record List...
Failed to execute (GetRecordList).
Failed at Friday, June 24, 2022 4:28:30 PM (Elapsed Time: 10 minutes 16 seconds)
```

user_ref_table was made like this:

```
list_dtypes = [i.str for i in df.dtypes]
# turn object type into 255 character string type
# turn datetimes type into M8[us] type
list_dtypes = ['<U255'  if d == '|O'      else d for d in list_dtypes]
list_dtypes = ['M8[us]' if d == '<M8[ns]' else d for d in list_dtypes]
# format as list of tuples (field name and adjusted dtype)
tup_dtypes =  [(f,t) for f,t in zip(list(df.columns.values),list_dtypes)]

# write to array, recasting the to_records array with .astype()
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(df.to_records(index=False).astype(tup_dtypes),user_ref_table)
```

the output table appears to be a sound database table. Here are the fields and datatypes for the 612 records returned with the last set of parameters I entered:

```
for f in fList:
    print (f.name + ": " + f.type)
OBJECTID: OID
DocumentClass: String
UniqueId: String
Creator: String
DocumentId: String
Roads: String
CityOrTownship: String
Book: String
Page: String
Sheet: String
LocationDescription: String
CreatedDate: Date
Year: String
image_url: String
```

Tried with both sde and fgdb databases.

Comment: Ok you have explained the origins of the table but what is `user_ref_table`? May be you written a load of nonsense for that output path? We need to see what this is.

Comment: @Hornbydd I assure you the table is not junk. Please see above. The table loads fine manually if I drag it to the table of contents from the sde database.

Comment: Finally you have said what it is, a table in SDE! I would suggest as a test put that table in a file geodatabase on your c:\ drive and then run your code on that version and report back the results.

Comment: Same issue with filegdb

Comment: Have you tried the approach in [sample code 2](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/table-class.htm) for a Table object?